# Querying InfluxDB with DateTime

Tags: python-3.x, influxdb

I am using influxdb_client python library for InfluxDB operations. I want to query the data for date-time range.

```
time_query = from(bucket: "my_bucket") 
|> range(start: time(v: 1623781800), stop: time(v: 1623954600)) 
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "my_data")
```

I have converted DateTime to timestamp using datetime library timestamp() function and am passing them for start and stop for query, although even if the data is present for that time range, I am getting empty results back when I do following:

```
result = self.query_api.query(query=time_query)
```

can anyone guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the time zone is different that you are passing due to which no results are available during that time:
Influx uses RFC 3339 format, by which you can know  the time-zone from the format. It displayed in the
 `“Z” syntax`.
“Z” stands for Zulu timezone which is the same with GMT or UTC  `“Z” means UTC+0`.
So if we put Z on the DateTime, it’s mean its timezone is `UTC+0.`
Below is the code to convert date and time to z format:

```
import iso8601
import pytz
_date_obj=iso8601.parse_date("2018-09-07T04:57:58.050-07:00")
print(_date_obj)
_date_utc=_date_obj.astimezone(pytz.utc)
_date_utc_zformat=_date_utc.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
print(_date_utc_zformat)
```

Output:

```
2021-06-18 04:57:58.050000-07:00
2021-06-18T11:57:58Z
```

To convert this date to timestamp:

```
ts = _date_utc.timestamp()
print("timestamp:-", ts)
```

Output:

```
timestamp:- 1624017478.05
```

To confirm if the timestamp corresponds to the date, I will use a unix command:

```
date -ud @1624017478.05
```

Output :

```
Fri, Jun 18, 2021 11:57:58 AM
```

You can use this timestamp in the query range.
**Note**: You can also click on the `raw data`  in the dashboard to see the time format that is stored and add it in your query.

[image]